# Setting Android Toast for Stacked Chart in AChartEngine

Tags: java, android, bar-chart, achartengine

How do I set a toast for a Stacked Column Chart in AChartEngine?

Comment: What do you mean by Tooltip? A Toast text or a displayed value above the bar?

Comment: Yes, Exactly the Toast text. When I clicl on Bar.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the AChartEngine demo. The [XYChartBuilder](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/browse/trunk/achartengine/demo/org/achartengine/chartdemo/demo/chart/XYChartBuilder.java) class does exactly what you need for line charts.

Just change line #167 to the one below and you will have it working on a stacked bar chart:

```
mChartView = ChartFactory.getBarChartView(this, mDataset, mRenderer, Type.STACKED);
```

Comment: mChartView = ChartFactory.getBarChartView(context, buildBarDataset(titles, values), renderer , Type.STACKED);
renderer.setClickEnabled(true);
renderer.setSelectableBuffer(100);
mChartView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
          public void onClick(View v) {
           SeriesSelection seriesSelection = mChartView.getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();
            double[] xy = mChartView.toRealPoint(0);
            if (seriesSelection == null) {
              Toast.makeText(context, "No chart element was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                  .show();
            } Not Working

Comment: I gave you the code for XYChartBuilder and explained you what you need to do. I tested myself and saw it working with bar charts. What else do you need?

Comment: m using Bar.Before return the Intent m using this: if (mChartView == null) {

mChartView = ChartFactory.getBarChartView(this, buildBarDataset(titles, values), renderer, Type.STACKED);
renderer.setClickEnabled(true);
renderer.setSelectableBuffer(100);
mChartView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
.....}
}
});

mChartView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
SeriesSelection seriesSelection = mChartView.getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();
if (seriesSelection == null) {
....
} else {
..return true;
}
}
});
}